# Is it possible to use `fmt.Fscan` or `fmt.Scan` for standard I/O?

Tags: go, io

About the standard I\O in Golang, all tutorial on the net, Without exception, discuss and use `bufio` which I tested and worked fine.

But my question is about using `fmt` package for reading standard input which either gives me errors or trapped in a loop.
According to the `fmt.Scan` documentation:

> Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive
>   space-separated values into successive arguments. Newlines count as
>   space. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is
>   less than the number of arguments, err will report why.

In the first sentence it is said that `Scan` reads from standard input, but it doesn't work at all!
also for `fmt.Fscan` which have this signature:

`func Fscan(r io.Reader, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`

when I enter a word, it throws exceptions and I can't even understand them!

So, is it possible to use these 2 methods to read standard input?

---

for more information this is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Print("pls enter name: ")

    var st *string

    n, err := fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, st)

    fmt.Println(st)

    fmt.Println(n)
    fmt.Println(err)
```

### }

EDIT: the error I get when entering a word in above code:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recover
ed]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x4977aa]

goroutine 1 [running]:
fmt.errorHandler(0xc04206be40)
        C:/development/Programming Languages/GO/src/fmt/scan.go:1031 +0x14f
panic(0x4b15a0, 0x544720)
        C:/development/Programming Languages/GO/src/runtime/panic.go:505 +0x237
fmt.(*ss).scanOne(0xc042044060, 0x76, 0x4a6460, 0x0)
        C:/development/Programming Languages/GO/src/fmt/scan.go:979 +0xc7a
fmt.(*ss).doScan(0xc042044060, 0xc04206bf48, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/development/Programming Languages/GO/src/fmt/scan.go:1040 +0x9d
fmt.Fscan(0x4de080, 0xc042004010, 0xc04206bf48, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x10, 0x4b36c0)
        C:/development/Programming Languages/GO/src/fmt/scan.go:123 +0xd2
main.main()
        C:/Users/Hamed/Documents/Go Projects/src/golang/learning/helloworld/firs
tApp.go:22 +0xe3
```

Comment: there are no exceptions in go, just panics, and it will be helpful for you to post what the panic stack trace actually is instead of making people guess.

Comment: @mpm I posted the panic message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I notice with your code is that you're passing a `nil` pointer to `fmt.Fscan`, i.e. you declare the variable `st` as `*string` but the address does not yet exist. It should be written:

```
var st string
_, err := fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &st)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

In my revised example, `st` now has a memory address (a `string`'s zero value is `""`), so it's address can be obtained using `&` and then passed to `fmt.Fscan`. Second, you should note how I handle `err` returned from `fmt.Fscan` - you simply print `err`, but what if an `error` is not returned? Then `err` is `nil` and your `fmt.Println(err)` is executed for no reason - it is idiomatic to handle returned `error`s conditionally, as is done in the above example.

However it is more common to use [fmt.Scanf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) like so:

```
var st string
fmt.Scanf("%s", &st)
```

Read the docs for more information. [The "fmt" package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to a `string` is unnecessary, you simply need to provide a reference to an initialised string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Print("pls enter name: ")

    var str string

    size,err := fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &str)

    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("Error reading name",err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Number of fields: %d. Text: %s",size,str)

}
```

You'll notice that multiple fields can be parsed:

```
func main() {

    fmt.Print("Please enter your first and last name seperated by a space")

    var firstName string
    var lastName string

    size,err := fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &firstName, &lastName)

    //...
}
```